GEE feature alignment in two featureCollections (same features but with different ID properties)
I have two sapefiles consisting of features + geometries that represent the same bounding areas on earth. Lets call them shp_D1 and shp_D2. Like in many shapefiles, every feature (polygon) in these featurecollections (FCs) have a property ID which is unique. However a polygon in shp_D1 has different ID than its counterpart in shp_D2.
(ex. a polygon  in shp_D1 has ID = 1000 and the same polygon in shp_D2 has ID= 723)
I am trying to relate features that have different IDs in the two shapefiles, but representing the "same" object. (I need to consider time-series of images "and" corresponding features in my analysis, therefore I can not use one FC for all my images covering a time period)
I wrote a mapping that seems to work correctly as I test it on one feature. It however seems not  efficient if I want to use it on FCs with many features.
Can you provide any comment for optimal modification of it?
One additional difficulty is that in shp_D1 there is a feature for an object but in shp_D2 that object might not present! In another word there are not exactly the same number of features in shp_D1 and shp_D2.
Here is my approach for finding the counterpart of 1 feature of shp_D1 in shp_D2:
// first, I calculate the centerpiece of polygons in shp_1 and shp_2 
//and add them as new properties to the corresponding FCs: 

var add_centroid = function(f){
   var centroid = f.centroid().geometry();
   return f.set('centroid',centroid);
 };

var shp_D1= shp_D1.map(add_centroid);
var shp_D2= shp_D2.map(add_centroid);


//second, another function returns a new FC with additional property
//'ID_aligned' that is (when maped over shp_D2) the unique identifier 
//of the same  parcel in the other collection (shp_D1) will be added 
//as a new property to the feature.

var add_aligned_ID = function(f){
   var f_centroid = f.get('centroid');
   var ID = ee.Feature(shp_D1.filter(ee.Filter.eq('centroid',f_centroid)).first()).get('ID');
return f.set('ID_aligned',ID);
};
var shp_D2_aligned = shp_D2.map(add_aligned_ID);

The problem is that it is not possible to do this for all features inside a FC with many features and even worst when there is no corresponding feature in the other FC.
Can you provide comments on the extension of this solution?

So-far I figured out that using ee.Join.inner() could be the closest GEE solution for this task. But it seems that for very large featureCollections it also has its limitations.

If your IDs are really numbers, you can do this as a raster operation, which should be faster and scale pretty large.  The basic plan is:

Add a centroid to each feature via map(), and set it as the geometry.
Render the IDs to two images via reduceToImage or paint.
Sample both images at all the centroids.

You'll have a collection that contains all the ID pairs.  Filter out anything that doesn't have two values.
